# What do you say to describe persons who made "un provino"?

Tags: grammar

Sometimes in television shows like "Big Brother" or "X-Factor" I heard people saying "Ho fatto un provino".

Suppose I want to say to another person that those persons have made "un provino", can I say

> Quelle persone, in particolare quelle che hanno partecipato al 'Grande Fratello', sono state tutte ***provinate***.

I.E., does "provinate" work there?

Comment: My reaction to reading that sentence was «"provinate" non si può sentire...» :-(

Answer (score 4):

While you might hear it spoken, it's not correct Italian written language. There is no single word to render the meaning but you can use a phrase

> Quelle persone, in particolare quelle che hanno partecipato al 'Grande Fratello', sono state tutte sottoposte a provini.

Another way in which you can convey a similar meaning, but not exactly, is to use the term 'selezionate' (selected) o 'scrutinate' (carefully examined).

> Quelle persone, in particolare quelle che hanno partecipato al 'Grande Fratello', sono state tutte selezionate (scrutinate).